# WebDriver - finding sibling elements

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, siblings

I have a html markup like this:

```
<html>
...
<body>
    ....
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Other Details</legend>
        <div>
            <input type='text' id='txt1' title='Detail 01'/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' id='txt2' title=''/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' id='txt3' title=''/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' id='txt4' title='Detail 04'/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    .....
<body>
</html>
```

This is what I want to do.

I need to rapidly traverse the screen, pick up all the textboxes and their titles. When I encounter a textbox that has no title (like two of them in my above example), I need to check if they occur under a fieldset, which they do. Now, for these textboxes without a title, all I have to do is to take the legend value of the fieldset and assign it to the textbox.

For example, the second and third textboxes in the above example do not have a title. In this case I want to do the following:

1. Take the legend value of the containig fieldset (in this case, "Other Details")
2. Derive the position of the textbox in the fieldset and append it to the fielset legend like Other Details 2
3. Do the same thing for the third textbox.

I achieved step 1. When I am in step 2, I need to find out the position of the textbox in the parent fieldset. I have my selenium webdriver code below:

```
WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("txt2"));
List<WebElement> precedingSiblings =
  textbox.findElement(By.xpath("preceding-sibling::input[@type='text' or @type='Text' or @type='TEXT']"));
String myTitle =
  fieldSetLegend + " " + Integer.toString(precedingSiblings.size()+1);
```

I expect this code to give me the value of myTitle to be Other Details 2 and Other Details 3 for my second and third textboxes.

But the problem is, everytime I hit precedingSiblings.size(), it always returns 0. That is because each input is contained within a div and hence has no siblings.

Now, I want to know of a way through which I can find at what position my current element is within the containing fieldset.

Please help.!!!

Answer (score 0):

What about navigating to the parent `div` finding *it's* preceding sibling & then finding the relevant `input` from there.

Roughly:

`parent::div/preceding-sibling::div/input[@type='text' or @type='Text' or @type='TEXT']`

Comment: I tried that and it works for the current example. But what I'm trying to do is a bit generic. Let's say in some cases, there might not be a div enclosing the inputs. I am looking for a generic way of finding the position.